# From combinatorics to probability theory: translating a solution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider the following problem.

[image]

I'm fairly new to probability theory, but have some experience with combinatorics. For that reason, after failing with a probabilistic approach, I approached the problem from a combinatoric perspective.

Firstly, notice there are $4!$ ways to arrange the four components. We do not care for permutations in the functioning components and therefore we will only consider $\frac{4!}{2!}=12$ orderings. Out of those $12$ orderings only two start with defective components. Then $P(Y=2)=\frac{2}{12}=\frac{1}{6}$.

Similarly, one arrives to the conclusion that $P(Y=3)=\frac{1}{3}, P(Y=4)=\frac{1}{2}$, and the problem seems to be solved.

However, I was still curious as to how one would formulate the problem in terms closer to probability theory. I attempted the following formulation, but I'm still unsure of whether  it is formally correct.

---

Let $S$ be the sample space where each $E\in S$ is a specific ordering of the components. Then there are $|S|=4!=24$ possible sample points. Let $A_i, B_j$ be the events that $A$ is the $i$th component, $B$ the $j$th component, respectively. Then it is clear that

$$\begin{align} P(Y=2)&=P\Big((A_1 \cap B_2 ) \cup (A_2 \cap B_1)\Big) \\ & =P(A_1 \cap B_2) +P(A_2 \cap B_1) \\ &=\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{3} \\ &=\frac{1}{6}   \end{align}$$

For $P(Y=3) $ the formulation is equivalent:

$$\begin{align} P(Y=3)&=P\Big(\big(A_1 \cap B_3 ) \cup P(A_3 \cap B_1\big) \cup \big(A_2 \cap B_3 ) \cup P(A_3 \cap B_2\big)\Big)\end{align}$$

which under the exact same logic gives $P(Y=3)=\frac{1}{3}$. In the same manner, $P(Y=4)=\frac{1}{2}$.

It is clear the results match. What I want to be sure about is whether my formulation in terms of probability theory is formally sound and correct, since I'm barely buildnig a basic understanding on the subject.

Comment: On a side note, I don't think you care about the order of the defectives either.

Comment: Oh, that's true. Not caring for the order of the defectives removes the two possible orderings I'm considering (quoting myself, "Out of those $12$ orderings only two start with defective components"). So the solution does not change ($\frac{1}{6}$ orderings instead of $\frac{2}{12}$ would be considered). Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

For this problem, your probabilistic approach is correct. But I would use the following alternative: The sample space consists of $\binom{4}{2}=6$ outcomes. You have four components (in order) and there are $\binom{4}{2}=6$ ways to choose a set $S\subset \{1,2,3,4\}$ of two defectives. Each of these sets $S$ is equally likely. For each set $S\subset \{1,2,3,4\}$ of two defectives, $\max S$ is the time the second defective is detected. There is one such $S$ with $\max S=2$, two with $\max S=3$, and three with $\max S=4$. Dividing each of these numbers by $6$ gives your probabilities $1/6$, $1/3$, and $1/2$.

This approach may be simpler/more generalizable. For fixed $n,k,r\geqslant 1$ ($ k\leqslant r\leqslant n$), there are  $\binom{r-1}{k-1}$ ways to choose $S\subset \{1, \ldots, n\}$ with $|S|=k$ and $\max S=r$. This is because the largest member of $S$ is $r$, and there are $\binom{r-1}{k-1}$ ways to choose the $k-1$ smaller elements of $S$. Applying this with $n=4$, $k=2$ and $r=2,3,4$ yields the counts of $1$, $2$, and $3$ I mentioned above.

Answer (score -1):

Shortcut.

With a sample space of $~\displaystyle \binom{4}{2}~$ there is only one way (out of $6$) that exactly $2$ tests are made.

There is a $~\displaystyle \frac{2}{4} = \frac{1}{2}~$ probability that the $4$th component is bad.  Exactly $4$ tests will be required if and only if the $4$th component is bad.

Then the probability that exactly $3$ tests are needed must be

$$1 - \left[\frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{2}\right].$$